# iOS keychain and encryption keys, how to keep safe until stored

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to store some encryption keys which I use for data transfer in the keychain to keep em safe.

My issue is, how do I keep em safe until I get them into the keychain? If I hard code em into the app, and add them to the keychain on launch the first time, then a hacker would be able to retrieve them by decompiling, any input is highly appreciated.

I would like to add that my validation of the data transfers are also dependent on a user password, which is safely stored in the keychain, but would still like to keep my encryption keys safe.

Thanks.

Comment: Cause in most cases my problems are still unresolved

Comment: Sounds reasonable enough to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 3 words:    SSL web service

Comment: Would you use SSL web service for all data transfer, or just fetching the encryption keys?